# Get the memory usage of the actual terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm trying to get the proceses of the **actual** terminal which are blocked, running, or ready for execution. I cant figure out to use ps or top... Can someone tell where to get that info from?

Comment: by "terminal" you mean the window (xterm/rxvt/kterm/etc.)? Or the shell that's running in that window (or remote session)? Actual TTY's/PTY's don't use a process.

Answer (score 1):

```
terminal="konsole"
 ps auwx|grep $terminal|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $NF ": PID:" $2 " CPU USED:" $3 " MEM USED:" $4 }'
/usr/bin/konsole: PID:3550 CPU USED:0.0 MEM USED:0.7


 terminal="terminator"
 ps auwx|grep $terminal|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $NF ": PID:" $2 " CPU USED:" $3 " MEM USED:" $4 }'
/usr/bin/terminator: PID:3616 CPU USED:0.7 MEM USED:0.7
```